How to Export Vulnerable Dependencies List in IntelliJ IDEA?
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for my Java project, and I've recently become concerned about the security of my dependencies. While IntelliJ IDEA does a great job of identifying vulnerable dependencies within my project, I'm struggling to find a way to export this information for further analysis and documentation.
I've checked the Project Structure settings and inspected the Libraries section, where I can see the dependencies marked as vulnerable. However, I couldn't find any built-in feature in IntelliJ IDEA to export the list of these vulnerable dependencies.
I've also explored the JetBrains Plugin Repository to see if there's any plugin available that offers enhanced dependency analysis features, including exporting lists of vulnerable dependencies, but I couldn't find one that specifically addresses this issue.
Is there a straightforward way or perhaps a plugin available that allows exporting the list of vulnerable dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA? I want to be able to document and analyze these vulnerabilities further, so any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

No such functionality at the moment I'm afraid. You are welcome to upvote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-148322
